# Google App Script Make text within a document readonly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a library that is adding data to a shared document. Is it possible to keep the document editable save for specific word patterns? For example every text between two * * can't be modified by users who aren't the owner?

Comment: Yes. use protection based on value and regex

Comment: The protection class only seems to be accessible through the SpreadSheet suite service. To be clear I am specifically trying to do this within a document. Do you know if that is possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Google Document in no way to lock part of document. It is possible in SpreadSheets only (known as protected ranges).

Bus is here different way to get similar effect. You can share the Document as read-only (view only) and write [Google Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) what provide custom editor interface to User. The script will have set **Execute the app as** permission to You. That mean, only You and your Script can edit the Document and in Script you can write write custom protection.